# ORA-00904: "GET_JAVA_PROPERTY": invalid identifier - 11gR2

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, linux

In Oracle DB 11.2.0.4, linux 6.7 single instance

select get_java_property('java.version') from dual;

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
SQL> select get_java_property('java.version') from dual;
select get_java_property('java.version') from dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "GET_JAVA_PROPERTY": invalid identifier
```

I can't find anything on this ORA-00904: "GET_JAVA_PROPERTY": invalid identifier, anyone know why this happens?

This works fine

```
SQL> SELECT  dbms_java.get_ojvm_property(PROPSTRING=>'java.version') FROM dual;

DBMS_JAVA.GET_OJVM_PROPERTY(PROPSTRING=>'JAVA.VERSION')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1.6.0_191

SQL>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, you found it somehow, didn't you?

It was never part of the database officially, it is just some custom function you can find on the Internet. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28164252/how-to-check-jdk-version-in-oracle

```
create function get_java_property(prop in varchar2)
return varchar2 is
language java name 'java.lang.System.getProperty(java.lang.String) return java.lang.String';
```